# JavaScript promise resolving with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, es6-promise

I don't understand why the first setTimeout function works but the second one doesn't. The first one is commented out when I run the second setTimeout. But instead of resolving after 3 seconds it resolves immediately.

I'm new to the whole 'promise' thing and the tutorial I'm working through uses promises with setTimeout a lot.

```js
  let promise = new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {

     /* why does setTimeout work with this one... */
     setTimeout( () => resolve( 'Job\'s done!!!' ), 3000 );

     /* but not with this one */
     setTimeout( resolve('done'), 3000 );
  } );

  promise.then(
     result => alert( result )
  );
```

Comment: because second one calls the method and returns what it returns to be called by setTimeout....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/* why does setTimeout work with this one... */
 setTimeout( () => resolve( 'Job\'s done!!!' ), 3000 );
```

when the timeout occur you call a function `() => ...` wich when  executed till resolve the promise

```
/* but not with this one */
 setTimeout( resolve('done'), 3000 );
```

here you actually resolve the promise (you execute the result function) and pass the result to the setTimeout function.

Writing

```
() => resolve( 'Job\'s done!!!' )
```

is the same as

```
function() {
    resolve( 'Job\'s done!!!' );
}
```

Comment: Yes that actually makes perfect sense. Thank you