# Debugging techniques in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, promise

The following is a snippet of Redux code I'm debugging, nothing special really. My question is about debugging it in Chrome Dev Tools.

The problem is setting breakpoint (bp) in the callback  `.then(({ data }) => dispatch({` . I can set a bp on this line but because of the arrow function dispatch I can't set a bp on `user: data.results[0],` within this function.

What can I do to set a bp so that I could inspect `data` or `data.results[0]`
Can I somehow debug into the promise chain ?

```
export const login = (username, password) => (dispatch) => {
  return dispatch({
    type: LOGIN,
    payload: {
      username,
      password,
    }
  })
  .then(({ data }) => dispatch({
    type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    payload: {
      user: data.results[0],
    },
  }))
  .catch((error) => {
    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_FAIL,
      payload: {
        error: error.message,
      },
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: why not just wrap the call to `dispatch` in braces in the same way as the .catch? then it's a separate statement that you can breakpoint on. Yes, the final code doesn't necessarily need it, but good code let's you debug easily too - go with what makes your life easiest, not necessarily what's the absolute cleanest code

Comment: Supposedly Chrome can [handle breakpoints on inline functions & arrows](https://umaar.com/dev-tips/129-inline-breakpoints/) now. Didn't work for me when using sourcemaps though - but you might have more success

Comment: Cheers James & Codingintrigue

Answer (score 0):

Replace .then function with text given below:

```
  .then(function({ data }) { 
    dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        payload: {
          user: data.results[0],
        },
      })
    })
```

Now you should be able to debug.

You can refer [JavaScript promise resolving with setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551778/javascript-promise-resolving-with-settimeout?rq=1) for more understanding of => and function(){}

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried

```
debugger;
```

?

It's same of break point, but don't forget to remove after debugging =)

Comment: This would be redundant. In order to introduce a `debugger;` statement, you would need to introduce a code block. Which you could put a breakpoint on anyway...