# Why can I not call resolve() for Promises in SetTimeout Function directly

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, settimeout, resolve

I have two versions of a sleep function, one is waiting for the resolve the other isn't:

```
function sleephelper1(ms) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(() => resolve('done'), ms);
    })
  }

  function sleephelper2(ms) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve('done'), ms);           
    })
  }
```

Then I call either sleephelper1 or sleephelper2:

```
async function test(){
var test = await sleephelper1(3000);
console.log(test)
console.log("exit test function")
  }

test()
```

The first one is waiting 3 seconds before in resolves. But sleephelper2 ist not working properly. The code gets executed immediatly.
I thought that SetTimeout can delay the call of a function by a given amount of time. Is resolve() not a function ?
I have found this post [JavaScript promise resolving with setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551778/javascript-promise-resolving-with-settimeout) which is quite what I am asking here, exept that I am using async await. Also I did not get the explanation. Could somebody explain to me why this behaves the way it does ?

Comment: In `setTimeout(resolve('done'), ms);` `resolve('done')` is executed and its return value is then used as the first argument of `setTimeout`

Comment: Also, if you just need a `sleep` function and you don't really care about what it returns you could just do `new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000))`, which will call the `resolve` function after some amount of seconds, instead of calling it immediately the way you're currently doing it.

Comment: "*Is resolve() not a function ?*" - no, the result of the expression `resolve()` is not a function. `resolve` on its own is.

Comment: That was exactly what I was unsure about. I thought that what ever I give as the first argument of the SetTimeout function will be executed after the given milliseconds. But the argument gets evaluated first and the result will be "executed" after the given milliseconds. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
setTimeout(() => resolve('done'), ms);
```

This means "create a function with the text `() => resolve('done')` and pass it into setTimeout". setTimeout will wait the specified amount of time, and then call that function.

```
setTimeout(resolve('done'), ms);
```

This means "immediately call `resolve('done')` and pass its result into settimeout". the return value from resolve is `undefined`, so undefined is passed into setTimeout. There is thus no function for setTimeout to run 3 seconds later.

Comment: Thanks, that really made me understand.
So the first argument of the SetTimeout function is "executed" and the result will be called after the given amount of time.